# Changing font within verbatim to allow unicode character

Tags: formatting, unicode

I am using XeLaTeX with [Ubunto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu) as the mono font. I would like to include a ␣ character, either directly as a unicode character or using `\textvisiblespace`. The character doesn't print, which I assume is because the font can't support it.

So I'm looking for a work-around and have two related questions:

1. Is there a way to change the font within `Verbatim` so it only affects certain characters? I'm wondering if I can change the font only to print this particular character, and then revert to Ubunto Mono.
2. Is there an easy way to see which fonts allow which characters? That is, how can I find fonts that will print this character?

I'm looking for any way to incorporate this symbol while still having flexibility on which font I use, so any advice on how to proceed would be great. Thanks!

Comment: which release of latex do you have the 2018-12-01 release has   Provide visible space in \verb* also for XeTeX and LuaTeX (github/69)

Comment: I believe I have whatever’s current. I’ll give it a try.

Comment: the log file of every document shows the version with a message. The current version is `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3`

Comment: OK so we have to use `\verbvisiblespace`, right?

Comment: a normal space should work in `verbatim*`